# Selenium Element is not clickable at point

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I have a cucumber script that's testing my ui using selenium, if i run it locally using mvn it seems to be running just fine, however if I trigger it using jenkins, then I'm getting the above error. Anyone else seen this issue?

I tried resolving this issue by adding a wait until element is visible

Below is my code:

```
public void userClick() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);

    w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Mine']/parent:span/parent::a")));

    d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Mine']/parent::span/parent::a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my resolution is the problem `chromeOptions.addArguments(window-size=1920,1080");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated` use `elementToBeClickable` and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='Mine']]"))).click();
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Mine']"))).click();
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just tried it, seems like no matter how long I set the timeout, the element won't become clickable. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you share the url to investigate?

Comment: It's an internal url, I'm not sure how to debug it though

Comment: Do you know how selenium works on jenkins? I'm thinking it might be because it's trying to open a browser

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because when you run your tests somewhere else there is different window size used (especially in headless modes) which makes the UI components overlap each other in some cases. This makes some of them intersect clicks which are assumed to be send to other components.

Waits wouldn't help here.

The solution would be to explicitly set the screen size to somewhat minumum supported for your app.